# when I run notepad.exe through os.popen in python the python program will not continue to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple program where you can type a command on one pc and it will run on an other pc and send the output back over WiFi but when I run notepad.exe the program will freeze and I have found out it is a problem with os.popen. This is the code for the sender (where you type commands):

```
import socket
import os

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);

ip = input("IP Address> ")
port = input("Port> ")

client.connect((ip, int(port)))

datac = client.recv(1024)
print(datac.decode())
if datac.decode() == "Request declined terminating program.":
    os.system("pause")
    exit()


while True:
    cmd = input("Command> ");
    
    client.send(cmd.encode())
    server_data = client.recv(1024)

    
    print(server_data.decode())
```

and this is the code for where the commands get executed:

```
import socket
import os

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);

serverSocket.bind(("127.0.0.2",9090));

serverSocket.listen();


while True:

    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = serverSocket.accept();

    answer = input("Accept connection request from " + clientAddress[0] + str(clientAddress[1]) + "? Y/N")
    print()
    if answer == "Y" or answer == "y":
        clientConnected.send("Request accepted.".encode())
        break
    else:
        clientConnected.send("Request declined terminating program.".encode())
        pass
while True:
    cmd = clientConnected.recv(1024)

    data = os.popen(cmd.decode()).read()
    
    clientConnected.send(data.encode())
```

Comment: It's not the `os.popen()` that's the problem, it's the `.read()` - that's going to block until the launched program exits, and you have no way of remotely causing the program to ever exit.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible

Comment: No, I'm saying you need to not call `.read()` - that's not going to return anything useful, anyway, with a GUI program.